# Javascript - The new method

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

If someone could break this down for me, so I can understand it, I'd be really greatful. I know it's used to create new object with apply method.

```
Function.prototype.new = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    var constructor = this;

    function Fake() {
        constructor.apply(this, args)
    };
    Fake.prototype = constructor.prototype;
    return new Fake;
};
```

Comment: if anyone gets stuck over this, here's a nice video clearing things up a bit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LftCfacTY0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the function `new` is used to inherit the prototype methods on newly created object from the one on which it is being called.

```
// new function is defined on the Function prototype so,
// it can be called directly from any function
Function.prototype.new = function () {
    // Caching the arguments array-like object
    var args = arguments;

    // this inside the new() refers to the function on which the `new` is called
    var constructor = this;

    // A fake constructor function/class
    function Fake() {
        // Calling the function with passing the context and the arguments
        constructor.apply(this, args)
    };

    // Adding the prototype members of the function on which new is called
    // On the new fake class
    Fake.prototype = constructor.prototype;

    // Retun new instance of the fake class
    // Actually returning only the prototypes here
    return new Fake;
};
```